# postgis ST_ClusterDBSCAN returns all zeros

Tags: postgresql, postgis

- Windows 10
- Postgres 9.4.11
- Postgis 2.3.2

I've just been fiddling with dbscan and created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbscan
(
  name text,
  latitude numeric(14,11),
  longitude numeric(14,11),
  geo geography(Point,4326)
)
```

...loaded the table with a few test lat/longs and ran:

```
UPDATE dbscan
SET geo = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326)::geography
```

To cluster:

```
SELECT name, 
       ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geo::geometry, eps := 1000000, minPoints := 2) 
                   over(order by name)
FROM dbscan
```

and the only results I get have 0 for the cluster id. (Interesting that it's "0" and not "null"). I've changed the "eps" parameter within a range of 1 to 10,000,000 so that doesn't seem to be it. ST_Distance works fine so the geo column is ok. Maybe Windows version? most of what I see on SO is linux...

Answer (score 1):

With eps=1000000 I can imagine that all points on Earth would belong to the same cluster number 0. You mentioned you tested eps in the range from 1 to 10,000,000. 1° is still around 111 kilometers for latitude, so you might need to try values like 0.01 or even lower.